# appengine java development server displaying source code

Tags: java, google-app-engine

When I access a jsp page like this on an appengine development server:

localhost:8888/index.jsp/

it's displaying the source code of index.jsp in the browser. if you access without the trailing slash (i.e. index.jsp) then it renders jsp but with the trailing slash (i.e. index.jsp/) it displays the source code

Any idea why is this? and how to fix it?

It seems to happen only in development server and not in production. Production gives a 404 Not Found error, which is fine.

I am using SDK 1.6.4

## web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaeehttp://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RegisterPage</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/register.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RegisterPage</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/signup</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

==========

so...

index.jsp -> renders page

index.jsp/ -> returns source code

register.jsp/ -> returns source code

register.jsp  -> renders jsp

signup/ -> renders register.jsp

signup -> renders register.jsp

so it seems like it's the urls with *.jsp/ that have the issue

Comment: Can you show the source code for index.jsp page? It would be great to find the exact problem.

Comment: Is it a typo or do you really have a `/` after the file name?

Comment: Usually this is a configuration error in the web server.

Comment: Please also post your web.xml.

Comment: if you access without the trailing slash (i.e. index.jsp) then it renders jsp but with the trailing slash (i.e. index.jsp/) it displays the source code

Comment: code for index.jsp won't help because it's the same issue with all jsps

Comment: so any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: does this only happen locally or does it also happen when you deploy the project?

Comment: yes, it only happens locally. in prod, it actually generates a 404 Not Found error.

Comment: Are you using a Web Server in front of your Servlet container (like IIS or Apache HTTPD) ? If so, this is often the result of the page being served by your web server as apposed to your servlet container (by using a wrong pattern in your plugin configuration).

Comment: No, I am simply using the appengine's sdk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move all the *.jsp files into the /WEB-INF directory, and update your web.xml.

This way the *.jsp files will not be accessible directly, and the source code will be hidden.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaeehttp://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RegisterPage</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/register.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegisterPage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/signup</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>IndexPage</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>IndexPage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: thanks, this worked! however, in the welcome file list, absolute paths don't work, so I had to use "index" instead of "/index"...

Answer (score 0):

I have the some problem when i have used "redirect" and apache tomcat 7, because the redirect is not supported in new version of apache. For solve your problem search news in changelog of your version of apache (if you use it) for the tag you used in your page, or publish code of your page to be able to suggest other solutions. May be that you're using deprecated tags. Also, keep in check the file localhost[DATE].log for more details